# ¿Como cargar los vídeos de la api de youtube?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de visualizar vídeos de una playlist de youtube llamando a la api, el problema lo tengo al cargar el vídeo en la etiqueta iframe, me aparecen 10 elementos todos con scroll porque es como si se cargaran los 10 vídeos que estoy tratando de obtener de la api hasta que termina petando la aplicación y me da este error: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed: Insufficient resources. Si me traigo datos como el titulo del vídeo o la descripción los obtengo sin problemas, es al querer obtener el vídeo para poder visualizarlo.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const API = 'borrada por seguridad'


export const YoutubeList = () => {
    const [allVideos, setAllVideos] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2Csnippet&maxResults=10&playlistId=PLB97yPrFwo5j60AxzdZVC3dOJvJy4Oxkp&key=${API}` )
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        const result = data.items.map(item=> {
            return {title:item.snippet.title, vId:item.contentDetails.videoId, id:item.id, description:item.snippet.description}
        })
        setAllVideos(result)
    });
}, []);

    return(
            <>
                {allVideos.map(item =>(
                <>
                      <iframe key={item.id} width="300" height="200" 
                      src={item.vId}
                      title='youtube'
                    >
                  </iframe>
                
                  <p>{item.title}</p>
                  <p>{item.description}</p>
                  </>

                ))} 

              
            </>
    )
}
```

Comment: ¿Todos los videos inician al cargarse? puedes agregar un flag para que no se inicien solo se carguen, eso puede reducir el problema de procesamiento que se esta presentando

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, no deberías colocar un API Key en una aplicación frontend, todos tus usuarios van a poder verla y copiarla, idealmente deberías hacer el fetch a YouTube desde tu backend y exponerlo a través de un API, asi tendrias un poco mas de control sobre el request a YouTube API.

El problema que tienes es que estas usando `contentDetails.videoId` como `src` en tu iframe. En `src` debe ir un URL valido, y `videoId` es solo el ID del video (por ejemplo, `MXZvQuG5mQc`). Podrías usar algo como:

```js
src={`http://www.youtube.com/embed/${item.vId}`}
```

Comment: Hola yorch, al final lo descubrí, ice lo que me has dicho en tu explicación, la api no es la real, como puedes ver es un texto que pone 'borrada por seguridad'. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.